# How to fetch only business hours for multiple days using datetime in php?

Tags: php, zend-framework

How to fetch  only business hours for multiple days where the time is  between  7a.m(begin_time) and 5p.m (end_time).

FOr example : fetch business hours for 2 days.

Output should be : day1 : 7 to 5 , days2 7 to 5;

Comment: There isn't enough information here for anyone to give you a good answer. More details would be useful.

Comment: i need to fetch data from mongo for hours within in shift timings to display in highcharts.

Comment: How to display hours for business hours only instead of all the time range between the dates?

Comment: What have you done so far? What are you data structures? Without any additional details you won't get any helpful answer soon.